# Languages to learn for making programs

Tags: windows

I was just wondering what languages you guys would suggest I learn if I wanted to make a program like the sticky notes program on Windows. I'm fairly new to program making (more of a website development guy) as if you couldn't already tell. 
Thank you guys so much!

~ Darren :)

Comment: Learn C. In that order.

Comment: @IInspectable ok, thanks!

Comment: Rationale: C is relatively simple, with just a handful of keywords, no invisible code generation, and a manageably small support library. It is also a perfect match for an OS exposing its services through a C interface, particularly when learning. There are enough invisible code paths in the OS API already. Choosing a programming languages that doesn't add invisible code certainly makes it easier to build a mental model. Even if you decide to not write C code at some point, it'll still teach you a lot of valuable things, that are relevant for any programming language. Still, Q is off-topic.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks man